# Performance Issue using DefaultMessageListenerContainer with CachingConnectionFactory

Tags: spring-integration, spring-jms

In our application we are using SingleConnectionFactory with DefaultMessageListenerContainer consuming from IBM MQ server, performance wise the app is doing pretty good, however on MQ end our application is opening too many new connections randomly. Here is the current config we have.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this instead of caching or single:

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.DelegatingConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="primaryRawInputConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="shouldStopConnections" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thank you Artem. What are the advantages of using this DelegatingConnectionFactory and how about DefaultMessageListenerContainer settings?

Comment: Read its JavaDocs, please. I don't see any problems with your `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` configuration.

Comment: I can still use <property name="cacheLevelName" value="CACHE_CONSUMER" />  on container?

Comment: Well, that's indeed better to cache consumer for the constantly listening container.

Comment: Awesome thanks...I wonder what happens in case queue manager is down, will my app try to reconnect to server?... I know at least I have that option for single or caching connection factory settings

Comment: That is already a container responsibility, not a connection factory. So, you’re good with what you have so far

Comment: Thank you.. will post you the results with new settings

Comment: Artem,I ran the test using DelegatingConnectionFactory, I don't see much improvement in performance compared to SingleConnectionFactory.

Comment: OK. Is there something what you can configure for the target MQ connection factory to make it scalable? I'm afraid there nothing we can do from the Spring perspective any more... At least you don't have problem like in case of caching factory...

Comment: Artem,  is there a  way we can still use SingleConnectionFactory & stop leaky connections to MQ?

Comment: You have to call its `resetConnection()` whenever you get a problem. You may consider to a `reconnectOnException = true` as well...

Comment: the property is already there in the code that has the issue...'<bean id="primaryConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
      <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="primaryRawInputConnectionFactory" />
      <property name="reconnectOnException" value="true" />
   </bean>'

Comment: Could it be a problem with MQ implementation itself?

Comment: As I said: there has to be something configured with the `primaryRawInputConnectionFactory` and that's already out of my scope...